# How to make terminal one desktop and unity another

Tags: unity, command-line

I am running Ubuntu 14.10 on my compaq presario laptop with a dual monitor setup. I would like to have unity on my larger screen and a full screen terminal on the laptop screen. Is this possible?

Comment: That shouldn't be too difficult. Open a terminal, drag it to the correct desktop, press F11.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal window "Control + Alt + T" and ensure it's running on your laptop screen, if not drag it to your laptop screen and press the F11 key which will make the terminal full screen on your laptop. Your standard unity window will be displayed on the second screen. I use this with my 14.04 triple screen setup and it works great.

Comment: not quite what i meant. Im looking to make my laptop display not have a desktop enviornment and my larger display to use unity.